# Primefaces datatable on row select javascript callback

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to call a javascript function whenever a row of a datatable is selected .I can't use ajax because I don't need to send a request and wait for a response from the server to fade in/out a menuBar.
One last remark ,the datatable is in single selection mode . 
Any help will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces Extensions comes to the rescue here.

Use

```
<pe:javascript event="rowSelect" execute="alert('Datatable rowSelect event called')"/>
```

If you need the row key for the selected row, use:

```
<pe:javascript event="rowSelect" execute="console.log(ext.params[0].value)"/>
```

**See also**

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/clientBehaviours/javascriptBehaviourAnother.jsf