# Primefaces dataTable JavaScript Callback on row selection with row number

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

With RichFaces it is possible to execute a JavaScript function when a single row is selected (via a click on the row) and passing the selected row number as a parameter like this:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable
    rowKeyVar="row"
    onRowClick="executeMeOnRowSelection(#{(row})"...>
```

I need to migrate this to Primefaces. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362860/primefaces-datatable-on-row-select-javascript-callback) Primefaces itself does not provide this functionality, but one can use Primefaces Extensions. However, when I try it like this:

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="row" selectionMode="single">

<pe:javascript event="rowSelect" execute="executeMeOnRowSelection(#{(row})"/>
```

...it would seem that Primefaces generates a JavaScript callback that does not get the selected row number, but is always called with the first row number (a look at the generated page reveals a hard coded value for the function parameter of the `executeMeOnRowSelection`).

Edit: To be more precise, the #{row} variable seems to not be evaluated when used directly under the p:dataTable tag. It is correctly resolved when used inside a p:column tag, but both

```
<pe:javascript event="rowSelect" execute="executeMeOnRowSelection(#{(row})"/>
```

and, for that matter,

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="alert(#{row});" />
```

end up with #{row} being replaced with an empty string (both placed as direct children of the p:dataTable tag).

Is there an error in the way I use the pe tag in combination with `p:dataTable`? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: try an `alert(this)` in the execute and check what the 'this' contains. Most likely also the html row in one form or another which also contains an index attribute that has the value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however alert(this) simply displays "Object: object" and alert(JSON.stringify(this)) displays "{}", so one would probably need other methods to investigate the content of "this" :-) Anyway, I would like to mirror the RichFaces solution as closely as possible, which would mean passing the #{row} variable on a per row basis to a JavaScript function.

Comment: sorry, I meant an console.log(this), then you can inspect it in the browser developer tool. Otherwise goodluck with staying with the richfaces way of doing things  as close as possible.